# AWS SQSで処理が終わったメッセージを削除したい

Tags: aws

AWS SQSを使ったキューシステムを構築しています。
Elastic Beanstalk上にnode.jsで実装したキューワーカーを使用しています。

以下のような処理の流れを想定しております。
1.リクエストを受ける
2.キューにメッセージを入れる
3.処理(DBへの登録)が終わる
4.メッセージの削除

現状、メッセージを削除していないため、使用したメッセージが
DeadLetterQueueとして残ってしまっているので
この問題を解決したいです。

公式ドキュメント( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#deleteMessage-property )のdeleteMessageを使用すれば良いということはわかるのですが、
それを一連の流れにどう組み込むのかがわかっていないです。
ご回答、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ワーカー上でReceiveMessage→何らかの処理→DeleteMessage というのが一般的な流れかと思いますが、それでは解決になりませんか？それともDead Letter Queueにたまったメッセージをどう処理するべきかという質問でしょうか。

Comment: >ワーカー上でReceiveMessage→何らかの処理→DeleteMessage というのが一般的な流れかと思いますが

こちらでやってみます。ありがとうございます

Comment: もし解決出来たのでしたら、ご自身で回答を書いて、それを承認してください。そうするとこの質問が解決済みとマークされます。

Answer (score -1):

ちなみに、SQSのトリガーを使ってlambda起動すればメッセージの削除は不要になります。
多分料金も安いですし。
もちろんlambdaで処理できる内容(DB登録など)ならばですけど。

Comment: これは質問の答えになりません。あなたが[一定の信用度を獲得すれば](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)任意の投稿に[コメントできる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)ようになりますが、それまでは[コメントで確認する必要のない回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)を投稿することを検討してください。 - [レビューより](/review/low-quality-posts/22572)

Comment: どういう意味でしょうか?単に私に答える権利がないってことですか?ここはお互いに疑問に答え合う場かと思ったのですが、違うんでしょうか?

Comment: それとも内容がおかしいという話でしょうか?